# I or Me, which is correct in the sentence "My wife insisted I go."?

Tags: grammar, pronouns

Got to read the following sentence in an article.

> But my wife insisted I go. Got to keep the wife happy :) so I went.

here, he says `insisted "I" go`. Is it correct? or `insisted me to go` will be the suitable one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use **I** when you are the subject and use **me** when you are the object.

> The dog barked at my wife and **me**.
>   My dog and **I** were going to a dog-shop.

You may remember a simple rule that will work ***most of the time***.

Remove all the rest and see if the sentence still makes sense.

> My wife insisted I go - Remove **wife** there! **I go** is correct and not **me go**.
>   The dog barked at my wife and me - Remove **wife** again! The dog barked at **I** does not fit.

Answer (score 10):

Great question. The word "insist" does not take a person as an object -- in fact, it doesn't take an object at all. It is an intranisitve verb meaning, approximately, "to push one's position strongly."

Instead, it introduces a new clause, usually introduced by "that" (which can be omitted in short sentences, which is a separate grammatical issue that has nothing to do with the word insist in particular).

In this sentence,

My wife insisted [that] [clause]

the clause is independent, so you insert another sentence there. The pronoun that follows [that], or insisted when "that" is omitted, is therefore a subject pronoun (because it is the subject of the next clause).

My wife insisted that we go.
My wife insisted that I go.
(etc.)

By the way, two things:

1. the word "beg" is similar to the word "insist" but takes as a direct object the person to whom you are talking. so "My wife begged ME to go" would be correct (the semantics are slightly different-- someone "begging" is usually more pitiable than someone "insisting.").
2. this difference between "me" and "I" is not like some other ones where the "rule" differs from what most native English speakers actually say: all native English speakers will actually say "I" here, even in extremely informal conversation.

Comment: What a very thorough and easy to follow explanation of the grammar behind this sentence!

Comment: Yes, this is a nice answer.  Except "insist" takes a prepositional phrase complement with "on", which is lost when the object of the preposition is a *that*-clause.